# What symmetry class does 1D spinless $p$-wave superconductor belongs to?

Tags: condensed-matter, superconductivity, topological-insulators

$Z_{2}$ topological invariant exist for [Kitaev model](http://www.google.com/search?as_epq=Kitaev+model).

> What symmetries does it conserve? And to what symmetry class it belongs to?
>   **The hamiltonian for kitaev model can be written as**
>   $$
> H=\sum_k \phi_k^\dagger \begin{pmatrix} \xi(k) & 2i\Delta \sin(k)\\ -2i\Delta \sin(k ) & -\xi(k)\end{pmatrix}\phi(k)
> $$

Comment: @AndrewMcAddams I don't understand what do you mean by spontaneous symmetry breaking here?

Answer (score 3):

It belongs to the symmetry class of **no symmetry**. i.e. the only symmetry is the fermion-number-parity conservation $Z_2^f$, which is always the symmetry of fermionic systems. See my paper http://arxiv.org/abs/1111.6341 for a discussion on the **full-symmetry group** $G_f$ for fermion systems.

Answer (score 2):

The Kitaev model belongs to class D of the Altland-Zirnbauer classification. Here's the periodic table of non-interacting (gapped) fermionic topological systems.

[image]

The one circled in red corresponds to the 1D $p$-wave superconductor (or Kitaev chain). As you can see from the symmetry columns, it only possesses particle-hole symmetry ($\Xi$), while the time-reversal symmetry ($\Theta$) and the so-called chiral symmetry ($\Pi = \Theta \Xi$) are explicitly broken.

Comment: the time reversal symmetry for spinless hamiltonian can be checked using equation $h(-k)=h(k)^*$ and by using this equation it seems that above hamiltonian is time reversal symmetric so what I am missing here?

Comment: Just the fact that you are studying a spinless system implies time-reversal symmetry is broken. Electrons are **spinful** particles. However, electrons can be *effectively* made spinless by spin-polarizing them with a magnetic field (internal or external). In general, some form of magnetic order needs to be present in order to create a Kitaev chain. Magnetic order, by definition, breaks time-reversal symmetry.

Comment: here we are not considering spin degree of freedom so we can't talk about magnetic order or spin degree of freedom ?

Comment: Yes, we have to freeze out the spin degree of freedom. There are many ways to do that: external magnetic field, intrinsic magnetism, etc. For example, in the Kouwenhoven experiment (http://dx.doi.org/10.1126/science.1222360), they used an external magnetic field, whereas in the Yazdani experiment (http://dx.doi.org/10.1126/science.1259327), they used a ferromagnetic chain of iron atoms.

Comment: @NanoPhys ,Isn't The hamiltonian as written in the question belong to BDI class ? How do i compare it with

Comment: a similar post:http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/156963/does-time-reversal-symmetry-hold-for-kitaev-model-1d-spinless-p-wave-superc